# No out of bounds error

Tags: c, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this code in C which takes in bunch of `char`s

```
#include<stdio.h> 
# define NEWLINE '\n'
int main()
{

char c;
char str[6];
int i = 0;
while( ((c = getchar()) != NEWLINE))
{
        str[i] = c;
        ++i;
        printf("%d\n", i);
}

return 0;
}
```

Input is: testtesttest

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
117
118
119
120

My questions are:

1. Why don't I get an out of bounds (segmentation fault) exception although I clearly exceed the capacity of the array?
2. Why do the numbers in the output suddenly jump to very big numbers?

I tried this in C++ and got the same behavior. Could anyone please explain what is the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1239938/608639), [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646973/608639), etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. C doesn't check array boundaries.  A segmentation fault will only occur if you try to dereference a pointer to memory that your program doesn't have permission to access.  Simply going past the end of an array is unlikely to cause that behaviour.  Undefined behaviour is just that - undefined.  It may *appear* to work just fine, but you shouldn't be relying on its safety.
2. Your program causes undefined behaviour by accessing memory past the end of the array.  In this case, it looks like one of your `str[i] = c` writes overwrites the value in `i`.
3. C++ has the same rules as C does in this case.

Comment: I thought some C compilers allowed you to select array bounds checking at the price of slower run-time, or is that C++? Look under arrays http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Sure, it can be a feature for some compilers but bounds checking is not part of the standard itself.

Comment: You're correct Marlon . However, if it's available in the compiler, then it could be a useful tool.

Comment: Sure, clang will do it for some cases if you pass `-fcatch-undefined-behavior`.  That doesn't mean it's part of the language, though.

Comment: The `gcc` equivalent is `-fsanitize=undefined`. The `-ggdb` flag also helps; it causes compilation with extra debugging info, which can be the difference between having/not having line numbers pointing to the error in the code in `fsanitizer` output.

Answer (score 6):

When you access an array index, C and C++ don't do bound checking. Segmentation faults only happen when you try to read or write to a page that was not allocated (or try to do something on a page which isn't permitted, e.g. trying to write to a read-only page), but since pages are usually pretty big (multiples of a few kilobytes; on Mac OS, multiples of 4 KB), it often leaves you with lots of room to overflow.

If your array is on the stack (like yours), it can be even worse as the stack is usually pretty large (up to several megabytes). This is also the cause of security concerns: writing past the bounds of an array on the stack may overwrite the return address of the function and lead to arbitrary code execution (the famous "buffer overflow" security breaches).

The values you get when you read are just what happens to exist at this particular place. They are **completely undefined**.

If you use C++ (and are lucky enough to work with C++11), the standard defines the `std::array<T, N>` type, which is an array that knows its bounds. The `at` method will throw if you try to read past the end of it.

Comment: When a program segfaults, it is always the hardware that first recognizes that something is amiss, not the operating system. The OS is invoked by the hardware to handle the segfault, which may then load some data from disk, or provide a zero page, or deliver a signal to the offending process. Whatever the OS does, it is constrained to the granularity of the hardware page size. And that hardware page size happens to be 4kiB on X86.

Answer (score 3):

C does not check array bounds.

In fact, a segmentation fault isn't specifically a runtime error generated by exceeding the array bounds. Rather, it is a result of memory protection that is provided by the operating system. It occurs when your process tries to access memory that does not belong to it, or if it tries to access a memory address that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Because C/C++ doesn't check bounds.

Arrays are internally pointers to a location in memory. When you call `arr[index]` what it does is:

```
type value = *(arr + index);
```

The results are big numbers (not necessarily) because they're garbage values. Just like an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @R.. Yes there is: "I tried this in C++ and got the same behavior. Could anyone please explain what is the reason for this?".

Comment: A nit-picky point: arrays aren't pointers. They're just normal values.

Comment: They're more 'reference' kinda types. But under the hood they are pointers, just like references are actually internally pointers. And therefore they can be deferenced. And also cast to `type*`.

Comment: Arrays are ABSOLUTELY NOT pointers.  At all.  The fact that the array variable can decay to a pointer type in certain contexts is independent of that.

Comment: @CarlNorum Once again, learn how to read. Internally. That said, if you don't believe me, read the assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

Writing outside array bounds (actually even just performing the pointer arithmetic/array subscripting, even if you don't use the result to read or write anything) results in **undefined behavior**. Undefined behavior is not a reported or reportable error; it measn your program could do anything at all. It's very dangerous and you are fully responsible for avoiding it. C is not Java/Python/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is more complicated than it seems. The variable "str," in this case, is on the stack, next to other variables, so it's not followed by unallocated memory. Memory is also usually word-aligned (one "word" is four to eight bytes.) You were possibly messing with the value for another variable, or with some "padding" (empty space added to maintain word alignment,) or something else entirely.

Like R.. said, it's undefined behavior. Out-of-bounds conditions could cause a segfault... or they could cause silent memory corruption. If you're modifying memory which has already been allocated, this will not be caught by the operating system. That's why out-of-bounds errors are so insidious in C.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile like this:

```
gcc -fsanitize=address -ggdb -o test test.c
```

[There is more information here.](https://fuzzing-project.org/tutorial2.html)

Comment: `-fsanitize=undefined` is actually a much stronger diagnostic. `address` will only trigger when the code segfaults at runtime. In contrast, `undefined` triggers a runtime error for all undefined behavior, whether there's a segfault at runtime or not. Other `fsanitize` arguments exist too, documented in `man gcc`.