# I want this to crash, but it doesn't

Tags: c, arrays, string

seriously..
I'm an old hacker from the 80's and with some spare time
on my hands thought I'd 'C' what the fuss is about

( my background is Forth, which does things back to front
so I learn a lot about forcing lots of errors )

In this case I've set up a small array which I
thought would be 3 elements in size ( 0,1,2 )

If I run the compilation, I would have thought
I'd have got an out-of-bounds error, but no-
it compiles ok and runs sweetly

No great hurry on this one, but it's
not good for the little bald spot, all that scratchin'.

---

```
int main()
{
    char members[3][16];  // 3 elements, each 15 char long plus null

    printf("\n enter something..  ");
    scanf( "%s", members[4]);

    printf("\n and something else..  ");
    scanf( "%s", members[5]);

    printf(" %s  ", members[4]);
    printf(" %s\n", members[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unreasonable for you to write a program with bugs and then think that it's going to do what you expect. Fix the bugs and the code will do what you expect. Buggy code is much harder to understand and predict that correct code.

Comment: i hear what you say and agree. But occasionally once i have code that works, forcing an error makes sure i understand why we dont things that we dont. think of it this way: The unaware are unaware that they are unaware. However i dont go to extreme limits on it. like checking my letterbox backwards in case i n the future i found a space/time warp portal and am sending myself the instructions to build it

Comment: That doesn't work though. You can walk across the street without looking both ways, not get hit by a car, and conclude that it's safe. That would be a horrible mistake though. You crossed the street without looking both ways and didn't get hit by a car. There is absolutely no reason you should be surprised by this, and of course it doesn't mean it's safe. This is no head scratcher -- you got lucky.

Comment: This just come in from a parallel dimension 3 over: "The boys got too much time on his hands.." - anayway point taken David - many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C no out of bounds error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137157/c-no-out-of-bounds-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't do any bounds checking. (Forth doesn't either, so I'm not sure where the expectation came from.)

Overflowing an array is *undefined behavior*: it is allowed, but not required, to crash. In this case, the bytes just happen to be in the same virtual memory page as the stack frame where the local variable was placed. If the frame were towards the end of the page, the CPU would recognize a bad address and complain about the overflow.

If you go a few kilobytes or megabytes out, you will likely see something like you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Accessing an array out-of-bounds invokes **undefined behaviour**.  This means that anything could happen, including running without any apparent error.

Comment: This answer is disappointing, yet it received more upvotes than any other here. While your answer is technically irreprehensible, if you read along the lines you can see him asking why and when getting out of the bounds can be dangerous / yielding a SIGSEV. It is not a question about standardese, it is more a question about memory management and operating systems.

Comment: @akappa: This is the simplest answer (so far) that explains the symptoms.  I could delve into discussing stacks and virtual memory, but I don't think the question warrants it (in its current form).

Comment: @akappa - Getting out of bounds is **always** dangerous, especially as it is undefined. If it wasn't, it would be defined and safe!

Comment: @BoPersson: I know. I'm not trying to say that what Oli said is incorrect (far from it), I'm saying that the answer should dig more into OS details in order to give to the OP an of why it is so. Others attempted at doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically memory is allocated in 4 kB pages. Therefore there is some extra space after the last variable, and your buffer overrun goes undetected. If, however, there was another variable after your `members` array and you wrote to `members[4]`, that another variable would get corrupted.

Tools like valgrind and dmalloc are often used to detect buffer overruns. They work by allocating special guard regions around your variables and checking that no-one has written there.

Comment: NO more replies needed folks, you have better things to do

Answer (score 0):

You miss main return address on the stack and probably overwrite some not critical data of main's caller so your program isn't crash. Moreover on some platforms (like powerpc for example) stack isn't used for function call and return address is stored in the special register (it pushed to the stack when it is required). So it is normal that this incorrect program doesn't crash.

Update: moreover on some system stack grows up (to the higher addresses). At least in ARM stack growth is selectable.