# Dereferencing arrays that contain pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, malloc

I wrote a program the involved two rows of integers that would periodically swap places. So, what I did was allocate two separate pointers to integers that would model the needed rows. I then placed both of the pointers into a constant pointer array that would easily facilitate the swapping.

The problem I am having was by complete mistake. Take this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char* a = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    char* temp[] = {a};
    int i, h, k = 'a';

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a[i] = k++;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%c ", temp[0][i]);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

With output: `a b c d e`
[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/vmC34k)

I accidentally attempted to access the members of the array contained within the static array by second-order dereferencing: "[][]"

I did not think much of this event because everything compiled and ran perfectly, even giving the expected results at the output. The problem came when I ran a memory analysis and found that I was getting tons of addressing errors and alleged memory leaks.

So, to start the debugging process I wanted to come here and ask why this worked and if it's valid C syntax. I was under the impression that:

```
temp[0]
```

Would dereference to `char*`, `a`. It would then take a further dereference of `a` to access its members. Further, I was under the impression that:

```
temp[row][col]
```

Is translated to:

```
*(*(temp + row*col) + col)
```

at run time. As such, the double dereference of `temp[0][i]` should give an offset from `temp` and not access `a` at all.

---

What's more interesting is that this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char* a = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    char* b = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    char* temp[] = {a, b};
    int i, h, k = 'a', j = 'A'; 

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        a[i] = k++;
        b[i] = j++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(h = 0; h < 5; h++)
            printf("%c ", temp[i][h]);
        puts(""); 
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Does not compile when run at [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/vmC34k). However, this code *does* compile using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 and `gcc` in `c99` mode.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to properly do what I was attempting to do? That is, access members `a` and `b` that are contained within the static array `temp` without using really ugly syntax like:

```
*(temp[i] + sizeof(char)*h)
```

Comment: Your first program is completely fine, and your reasoning about addressing is correct (except `row*col` calculations). The second one accesses five indexes of `temp` while there only two available.

Comment: Arrays aren't "*dereferenced*".

Comment: @alk, Arrays are constant pointers to memory and as such are dereferenced when used. For example, some `int* foo[5]` array really is the same as a constant integer array that pointers to a block of memory `sizeof(int)*5`. It follows that `foo[2]` points to the third integer, but one may also use `*(foo+2)` to dereference to the same member. Perhaps you are correct in that the correct jargon was not used in the title, but everyone seemed to get the idea here.

Comment: I do not see any reason why to use incorrect wording by intention.

Comment: `int * foo[5] ` is an array of **pointers to** `int`. I has a size of `5 * sizeof (int *)`.

Comment: I did not intentionally do anything, I just don't see the difference given how the compiler interprets the array indexing brackets anyway.

Comment: You got me, I did not mean to add the asterisk. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but if you "*... did **not** intend to put an asterisk*, your statement "*foo[2] points to the third integer*" is wrong. Correct would be "*foo[2] **holds** the third integer*". The former is correct for `int * foo[5]`. However stating "*... `foo + 2` points to the third integer*" would be correct.

Comment: Oh boy, quite the pedant. Thank you again. I was referring to the fact that `foo` is a constant pointer and as such *(foo+2) directs the user towards the third integer.

Comment: "*quite the pedant*" err, not me but the subject: This is math! Never mind however .. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`temp[row][col]` is **not** equivalent to `*(*(temp + row*col) + col)`, but actually equivalent to `*(*(temp + row) + col)`.

Your second example code is incorrect because `temp` is an array of 2 elements, but you are accessing `temp[i]` with `i` ranges from `0` to `5`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I suppose I was thinking in the context of a `char**` with memory "blocks" corresponding to the rows .. or something like that. I get what I meant but it has no relevancy here.

Comment: Say I had some: `int temp[3][3]`, would it not be structured in memory as: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` ? Where we have symbolic "blocks" in this contiguous memory corresponding to the rows of the 2D array? That is, `1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9`. As such, if we want to access `temp[2][2]` arbitrarily, we would have to do: `*(*(temp+2*3)+2)`, correct? The first `col` in the expression that I included in the original post was `number of columns`, rather than `col` th8at was included in `temp[row][col]`. The expression you include: `*(*(temp + row) + col)` appears valid only for `char*` arrays.

Comment: ajay lists below a excerpt from the C99 standard, so it must be correct - I just do not see how. Are 2D arrays allocated using constant pointers to the rows? If so, that would make much more sense than what I was thinking and the above expression would therefore be valid.

Comment: @sherrellbc The compiler knows the element of `temp` is another array, so when it sees `temp + row`, it knows how much size advance to find the next element.

Answer (score 1):

You guessed it right when you thought `temp[0]` equals `a` and `temp[1]` equals `b`. But wait why are you going beyond that like you are trying to dereference something like `temp[2]`? You did not initialize this thing right!

Your program causes `undefined behaviour` by accessing memory past the end of the array. The compiler is not always obliged to give you an error message. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137157/c-no-out-of-bounds-error) question.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 standard §6.5.2.1 ¶2 says -

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is
>   identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

Therefore, the expression `temp[row][col]` is evaluated as

```
temp[row][col] --> *((temp[row]) + col) --> *(*(temp + row) + col)
|_______|  |
    |      |
   E1     E2
```

and not as `*(*(temp + row*col) + col)`. Please note the difference. Therefore, your first program is fine.

In the second program, the statement

```
char* temp[] = {a, b};
```

defines and initializes `temp` to be an array of `2` pointers to characters. However, in the `for` loop, you access the array as `temp[i][h]` and `i` ranges from `0` to `4`. Accessing elements out of the bound of an array is undefined behaviour. Therefore, your second program is wrong.