# malloc touching unallocated memory

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm wondering why my allocation is working. I created `ptr` which is a pointer and `ptr2` which a pointer on the same location than `ptr`.

Here's my code:

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* ptr2 = ptr;
*ptr2 = 1;
ptr2 = ptr+1;
*ptr2 = 2;
```

At the end I've an array of two integer like that :

```
ptr[0] = 1
ptr[1] = 2
```

My question is : why I can affect the value 2 to `ptr2` without error or warnings ? I only `malloc()`-ed for one integer place in my array, isn't it?

Comment: Undefined behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No out of bounds error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137157/no-out-of-bounds-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426910/is-accessing-a-global-array-outside-its-bound-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Use [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) if it is available to you; it will point out the error of your ways.  Writing outside the bounds of the allocated memory is undefined behaviour.  Anything may happen.  One of the things that may happen is that you'll get away with it.  If you wrote further out of bounds and did more memory allocation, you'd be more likely to get fatal problems.

Comment: Neither of the possible duplicates is entirely satisfactory — one deals with overflowing a local array and the other with overflowing a global array.  Surely, there must be another duplicate for overflowing dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The undefined behavior doesn't distinguish whether the errant pointer originated with an object of automatic, static, _Thread_local or allocated storage duration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is, by saying

```
  ptr2 = ptr+1;
```

you're pointing to out of bound memory. Next upon dererencing, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Now, the outcome of UB cannot be justified, in any way.

There is nothing inherent in C that *stops you* from accessing out of bound (or invalid) memory, but the outcome of doing so is UB.

That said, just a suggestion, you should always check the returned value of `malloc()` before using that pointer to avoid UB by dereferencing `NULL` pointer, in case of `malloc()` failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I want to make it better I can use something like `realloc` ?