# What is the output of this program Insert in beginning of an array in c and reason why is it?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() 
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int num,i;
    for(i=6;i>0;i--)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1];
    }
    printf("enter any no, ");
    scanf("%d",&num); // input 12
    a[0]=num;
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d",a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

the output is 
12
1
2
3
4
5
12
why???
there is no array memory problem when we do like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() 
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int num,i;
    for(i=6;i>0;i--)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1];
    }
    printf("enter any no, ");
    //scanf("%d",&num); 
    a[0]=12;
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d",a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

the memory of an array is same but the output is 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 (Now the output is change) 
so, when we use scanf so why the output is different

there is no mistake of Undefined Behavior and no mistake in length of an array

so plz give me the reason why this happen while using scanf????

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because the array `arr` doesn't have 7th element at index 6 (index range is 0 to 5).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646973/4389800 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9137157/4389800

Comment: in c there is no matter of index

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because you assign and print outside the array bounds. It is likely that `num` is placed just after `a` on the stack. So when you print `a[6]` the code happens to print the value of `num`.

Comment: sory sir, but in c u can print the any index no. of an array like you declear an array like "int arr[5];" after that u insert the value on 10 index no. like "arr[10]=20" after that you print arr[10] the ans is 20 (so why this will happen)

Comment: @AshishVerma You can *try* to print any index. However, if you use an index outside the area defined for the array undefined behaviour is invoked. That means that anything could happen. You could be afflicted by nasal demons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: but sir, if we do like this a[0]=12;  and remove the scanf command is perfectly work (so what is the reason);

Comment: @Ashish - There is no explanation. With undefined behavior *anything* can happen, including displaying what you expected. Or something totally different. There are no rules.

Comment: now the array contain 6 value  but when it contain 5 value the output us correct example now a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6} so the output of program is 12 1 2 3 4 5 12    and when a[]={1,2,3,4,5} so the output is 12 1 2 3 4 5 (in the condition when we take 5 element at initial time the result is up to mark it Insert in beginning correctly how????)

Answer (score 2):

It is **undefined behaviour** because you are trying to access array out of the bound.

**C11 standard say's :**

> **J.2 Undefined behavor**
>
> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   a[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)[7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

[Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means that "anything can happen".The program may crash or produce nothing or print expected output.

Comment: no, if we do like this  a[0]=12;   is perfectly work

Comment: @AshishVerma in your code i<=6 access the a[6] value, which out of bound.

Comment: sory sir, but in c u can print the any index no. of an array like you declear an array like "int arr[5];"  after that u insert the value on 10 index no. like "arr[10]=20" after that you print arr[10] the ans is 20

Comment: @AshishVerma Undefined Behavior means that "anything can happen". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: sory, but any thing can't happen in programing for every output some logic is there i what that???

Comment: @AshishVerma - read K&R C book, in that it is mentioned. that output can be anything. Its not logical, for some device you can come up with one logic but with other device it may fail. that's why undefined behavior

Comment: ok sir you are right , but that is condition of garbage value or increase datatype range ,,,,,,, if we do like this a[0]=12; and remove the scanf command is perfectly work (so what is the reason) the output is 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 and Insert in beginning is happen perfectly can u explain this

Answer (score 0):

Analysing your code:

```
void main() 
{
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};  //Array of 5 elements
int num,i;
//for(i=6;i>0;i--)         //i. Bound Checking Error.
for(i=5; i>0; i--)           //correct.
{
   a[i]=a[i-1];          //Trying to insert element 6 value over element 5. However you have only 5 elements in consecutive memory location. In i. Reference`
}
printf("enter any no, ");
scanf("%d",&num); // insert 12
a[0]=num;
for(i=0;i<=6;i++)  // you have only 5 elements trying to access 6 elements.
{
     printf("\n\n%d",a[i]);
}
getch();
}
```

**According to C standard its undefined behavior and is not recommended.**

Comment: i want to Insert in beginning of an array

Comment: What you want to insert?

Comment: any number take input on the console

Comment: Thats what you are doing in `a[0] = num;` getting the number from user and assigning it to the a[0] thats first index .