# in C, does empty char array[2000] contain all zero's?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I thought when you define an empty array like this
`char t[2000] = "";`
it would set all elements of that array to `0`, but when I create a 2000 size array, the 2000th element is not `0`. Same thing with 3000 size array, but other sizes like 100, contain all zeroes.

Why aren't all the elements `0`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char t[2000] = "";

    for (int i; i <= 2000; i++) {
        if (t[i] != 0) {
            printf("\n\nt[%i] is not 0\n\n\n", i);
        }
        printf("t[%i] = %i\n", i, t[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array `char t[2000]` has elements `t[0]`, `t[1]`, ... and `t[1999]`. Accessing the non-existent `t[2000]` is illegal. Your initialization sets all 2000 elements to `'\0'`

Comment: if you go beyond the array then it is undefined behavior

Comment: Note: `i` is not guaranteed to be initialized to `0`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1239938/1233251 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137157/no-out-of-bounds-error

Comment: Of course! Thank you

Comment: @JohnBode nice thanks for that tip! it should be for(int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++) ?

Comment: @xXxUserNamexXx: Nope. See my answer; you have the high bound set wrong too.

Comment: From the question title, `char t[2000] = "";` will contain all zeros. Any local array that *is initialised* any elements that are not specifically set will be `0`. But if the local array is *not initialised* all the values are indeterminate.

Comment: @xXxUserNamexXx:  Yes, although the test should be `i < 2000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2000 element array only has legal indices from 0 to 1999 inclusive. Accessing `t[2000]` is outside the array, invoking undefined behavior. It's not part of the array, it could contain anything (or just make demons fly out of your nose, whatever). This is why typical C `for` loops run until `i < arraylength`, not until `i <= arraylength`; you must exclude the length itself as an index.

Note that you have a second bit of undefined behavior when you fail to initialize `i` in the first place; you really need to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
```

Comment: Great thanks! Good to know with int i

Answer (score 1):

Your array only has elements from `t[0]` to `t[1999]`. When you try to access elements beyond that, you are going beyond the bounds of array and this results in undefined behavior.

When you try to access the element `t[2000]`, you are not guaranteed about what its value might be.

- It might store an value that was previously assigned to it sometime, might give you an **runtime error** or any other error. This cannot be determined and hence is called as **undefined behavior.**
- It might just seem to work fine and give the expected value without giving any errors(C doesn't check array boundaries).
- It might give you a value but not the one you expected but some previously stored value.

So, remember that whenever we loop an array or string of size `s`, always use the condition  - `for(int i = 0 ; i < s ; i++)` and not `i<=s` which will result in illegal access of `t[2000]`. You never know what result it might produce.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and explanation, real nice